# Romance one-shot about an emotionless girl

Tags: ningyo-hime-to-ouji-sama

This is a romance/shoujo one-shot manga.
There is a girl is considered a beauty but she is also emotionless, because of her lack of emotions she doesn't have any friends. Some girls call her a robot I think. One day a guy from the soccer team , who is also called a 'prince' by other girls, confesses to her but all she does is bow her head and leaves. The soccer guy doesn't give up and becomes friends with her. 
I remember one part where she is outside on the stairwell taking pictures of the sky and he asks to join her in taking pictures of the sky. This leads to them hanging out and taking lots of pictures together.

Eventually the girl thinks she's being played after some of the guys friends make a comment about how the prince can get anyone's heart except for hers. 
.        .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The manga is *Ningyo Hime to Ouji-sama*, by KYOUMACHI Hisa.

Synopsis from [Baka Updates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=110428):

> School life becomes too much for Sonohara Kokone when Sei-kun, who is as popular as a real prince at school, suddenly asks her out. They barely know each other due to her doll-like but expressionless features. So, why is he minding her so much!?

this manga is correct because I read it ages ago and remember it. :|

Comment: This generic synopsis does not answer whether or not this manga has the features of the girl doesn't have any friends, the prince plays soccer, they take photos of the sky, and the girl thinks she's being played. Please explain more why your answer is correct.

Comment: @seijutsu why? Can't people just check the manga for themselves to see if the answer is correct?

Comment: @miss.kim.k If everyone did that, this site would have about a tenth of the questions it has today. This is a site dedicated to helping others in those subjects, the answer, as it was posted, doesn't really help OP with figuring out whether your answer is correct or not.

Comment: @madara okay den